# If I setup a bootable disk do I lose my files?

Tags: live-usb

I want to install Ubuntu from a bootable USB drive.

I'm thinking of creating the bootable drive by following [these](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) instructions.

The drive I have is a 500GB USB External Drive. In it I have many files, videos, pictures and other stuff.

If I go on with this procedure, will I lose my files? Or will they be preserved?

Answer (score 1):

the drive will be formatted. Meaning: The files will be lost.

You could make an extra partition on your drive and install ubuntu live on that. This will preserve your files.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your help. I'll accept your answer as correct as soon as I'm allowed

Answer (score 0):

If you're in windows. You can shrink the 500GB partition and have separate space to install Ubuntu to avoid any file lost :)

[See how to shrink a drive in Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx)